# How to escape single quote in a string taken by YAML file using Sprintf

Tags: arrays, go, printf, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm using Go but I'm having issues while trying to get an array that contains a single quote, I'm making a query structure to create a .sql file with that query, the issue is with an array field that is adding double quotes instead of a single quote.

This is what I have:

Yaml File:

```
Name: 'Myname'
Age: 9
Dimensions ['go', 'lang']
```

Go code Syntaxis:

```
var Query string = "";
Query = fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO persons (name, age, dimensions) VALUES ('%s', %d, %q)")
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Query:
 INSERT INTO persons (name, age, dimensions) VALUES ('MyName', 9, ["go", "lang"])
```

I don't want "go" and "lang" double quoted, I want it as the YAML file came, with single quote.

Is supposed that "%q" escape the single quote...

any idea what to do?

Comment: by the looks of you have to do it separately: step 1 get the `["go", "lang"]` string, step2 `strings.Replace()` double-quotes `"` with single `'`.

Comment: What (Go) value are you supplying for that `%q` that produces `["go", "lang"]`? The behavior of `%q` depends on what value you give it BTW. Also, which database accepts array as `['go', 'lang']`? I'm familiar with `array['go','lang']` and `'{go,lang}'` but not the one.

Comment: I had to Create a variable and do a strings.join() due that is an array [], just joined with "','" and was modified to `Query = fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO persons (name, age, dimensions) VALUES ('%s', %d, ['%v'])")`